# Inkscape: placing adjacent objects

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to draw a circus tent with inkscape in the style of [this one](http://www.tamarinde.nl/PublishingImages/circus-tent.gif?Mobile=1&Source=%2F_layouts%2Fmobile%2Fdispform%2Easpx%3FList%3Df9784ff5-6ad9-47a3-b29d-2242dd19ccb8%26View%3Da931f1c4-6f32-4374-a782-a3ab401abce5%26ID%3D13%26CurrentPage%3D1). I'm unable to properly place the different parts of the tent together though, because there doesn't seem to be any overlapping. What tends to be the best strategy to draw something like this?

The way I'm currently doing it, is drawing the separate pieces and arranging them somewhat next to each other. But that isn't working out too well.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some images and show us what you have tried?

Comment: Added what I have so far, the thing is that I'm wondering what the general strategy for something like this is.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help you:

- Snapping. This probably solves most of your problems.
- Using the *align and distribute* tab.
- Creating new objects from duplicating existing ones.
- Create only one half; then mirror (use clones to preview results).

Comment: Can you give an example on how you'd do it?